# How to interface with Autodesk Maya 2014 built in renderer?

Tags: c++, plugins, maya

I am building a autodesk maya 2014 ray tracing plugin with the [maya c++ API](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2014/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/index.html). my plugin runs in maya but the output image is directly written to the hardisk, it's very clumsy.

I am trying to find a way to interface with maya built in renderer and thus seeing the output image in maya view port and getting the option to save the image within the maya interface.

I want the option to render my scene within maya using my ray tracing algorithm and watch the output image in maya (not writing the image externally to the disk).
There is almost no tutorials for writing maya plugins and how to use the maya API I could find by googling.

I will try to focus my question and add some more question regarding the implementation itself:

1. can you direct me to a tutorial for how to code an extension (like mental ray) in c++ using the maya API that will work within maya and will render and show the output of my custom ray tracing algorithm in maya view port?
2. and for the implementation itself: i am a little confused with all the coordinate systems used by maya and openGL. lets assume i found a perspective camera and its dag path using an iterator in the plugin itself, and i have all the scene objects vertices (again iterator within the plugin). how do i convert those vertices from model\camera\object spaces to screen space?
3. the same question as the second question but now instead of getting the vertices in screen space as before i want a way to print them in a maya view port?

Comment: This is too broad. Chop it down to multiple standalone questions.

Comment: See renderViewInteractiveRenderCmd.cpp example in the api folder